# Handle "Division by Zero" in Image Processing (or PRNU estimation)

Tags: math, image-processing, numeric, division, divide-by-zero

I have the following equation, which I try to implement. The upcoming question is not necessarily about this equation, but more generally, on how to deal with divisions by zero in image processing:

[image]

Here, `I` is an image, `W` is the difference between the image and its denoised version (so, `W` expresses the noise in the image), and `K` is an estimated fingerprint, gained from `d` images of the same camera. All calculations are done pixel-wise; so the equations **does not** involve a matrix multiplication. For more on the Idea of estimating digital fingerprints consult corresponding literature like the general [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-pattern_noise) or [scientific](http://proceedings.spiedigitallibrary.org/proceeding.aspx?articleid=1319409) [papers](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=4451084&tag=1).

However my problem arises when an Image has a pixel with value Zero, e.g. perfect black (let's say we only have one image, `k=1`, so the Zero gets not overwritten by the pixel value of the next image by chance, if the next pixelvalue is unequal Zero). *Then I have a division by zero, which apparently is not defined.*

How can I overcome this problem? One option I came up with was adding `+1` to all pixels right before I even start the calculations. However this shifts the range of pixel values from `[0|255]` to `[1|256]`, which then makes it impossible to work with data type `uint8`.

Other authors in papers I read on this topic, often do not consider values close the range borders. For example they only calculate the equation for pixelvalues `[5|250]`. They reason this, not because of the numerical problem but they say, if an image is totally saturated, or totally black, the fingerprint can not even be estimated properly in that area.

But again, my main concern is not about how this algorithm performs best, but rather in general: How to deal with divisions by 0 in image processing?

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean by "I_k is an image"? What is the mathematical model of an image?

Comment: It's a 2D Matrix. E.g. each entry in the Matrix corresponds to one pixel in the image; so the Matrix dimensions are equal to the resolution of the image.
Though keep in mind, that the math does not follow regular "Matrix calculation rules", as all operations are done element wise (take one pixel of I_k(x,y) and multiply it with W_k(x,y) in the numerator, for example)

Comment: Just as I thought. Then what do you mean by *dividing* by the sum of the matrices `I_k^2`?

Comment: Okay, let's just considere one particular pixel at (x,y), and only one image (d=1), then this boils down to: I_k(x,y)*W_k(x,y) / I_k(x,y)^2.
And now, if I_k(x,y) is 0, then we would divide by zero...

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use subtraction instead of division; however subtraction is not scale invariant it is translation invariant.

[e.g. the ratio will always be a normalized value between 0 and 1 ; and if it exceeds 1 you can reverse it; you can have the same normalization in subtraction but you need to find the max values attained by the variables]

Eventualy you will have to deal with division. Dividing a black image with itself is a proper subject - you can translate the values to some other range then transform back.

However 5/8 is not the same as 55/58. So you can take this only in a relativistic way. If you want to know the exact ratios you better stick with the original interval - and handle those as special cases. e.g if denom==0 do something with it; if num==0 and denom==0 0/0 that means we have an identity - it is exactly as if we had 1/1.

Answer (score 0):

In PRNU and Fingerprint estimation, if you check the matlab implementation in Jessica Fridrich's webpage, they basically create a mask to get rid of saturated and low intensity pixels as you mentioned. Then they convert Image matrix to single(I) which makes the image 32 bit floating point. Add 1 to the image and divide.

To your general question, in image processing, I like to create mask and add one to only zero valued pixel values.

```
img=imread('my gray img');
a_mat=rand(size(img));

mask=uint8(img==0);
div= a_mat/(img+mask);
```

This will prevent division by zero error. (Not tested but it should work)